# ER_PARSE_ERROR - Node MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

I am new to node and mysql. I am developing an API.

Here's the case:

I want to make a web service and make two insertions on two different tables with a single query.

```
    function createTask(taskInfo, callback) {
    return db.query(`start transaction;
    insert into task values(null,'${taskInfo.name}','${taskInfo.description}',${taskInfo.dueDate},'${taskInfo.difficultyId}','${taskInfo.course_id}') ;
    insert into evaluated_tasks (student_id, task_id)  
        (select id from user where type=1) , (select max(id) from task);
    commit;`
    , callback)
}
```

I am coming up with

> ER_PARSE_ERROR

**Update**

I have two tables:

1) task (id, name, description, due_date, difficulty_id, course_id)

This table holds a list of tasks.

2) evaluated_tasks (student_id, task_id)

This table holds the tasks which are to be evaluated. When a task is evaluated for a specific student it has to be deleted from this table.

Now I want to create a new task. The thing is that after creating a new task then I have to insert to my `evaluated_tasks` table as many records as my students count. So each record will be a pair of two columns *student_id* and *task_id*.

The goal is to make all these on a single query. From my little research I saw I can use `start_transaction` and `commit` for `mysql`. The point is there might be a syntax error on this query.

Comment: First off, query will execute a single query. Also, SQL queries end with a semi-colon __;__ Lookup multi_query

Comment: Simplify and test.  When you have a simpler example with the problem, post another question.

Comment: I got some little more explanation.